# ETIMEDOUT on sending email to SMTP server on paid Heroku account

Tags: node.js, email, heroku, nodemailer

I'm trying to implement a sending email functionality with the [`nodemailer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) package in a Node.js app, running on Heroku.

I'm sending the following request to the mail gateway:

```js
const CONFIG_MAILER = Object.freeze({
    auth: {
        pass: authPass,
        user: authUser,
    },
    host: SMTPhost, // no Gmail server, no need in "less secure app access"
    port: SMTPport, // 25
    secure: false,
    sender: senderEmail
});

const MAIL_OPTIONS = Object.freeze({
    from: senderEmail,
    html: emailBody,
    subject: emailSubject,
    to: recipientEmail
});

const TRANSPORTER = nodeMailer.createTransport(CONFIG_MAILER);

await TRANSPORTER.sendMail(MAIL_OPTIONS);

TRANSPORTER.close();
```

On the **free** dyno, the email sending works, but when I deployed the same codebase with the same settings to the paid **hobby** dyno, then emails are not sent, instead I get a timeout error:

```js
app[web.1]: transporter.verify: Connection timeout
app[web.1]: Error: Connection timeout
app[web.1]: at SMTPConnection._formatError (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:774:19)
app[web.1]: at SMTPConnection._onError (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:760:20)
app[web.1]: at Timeout. (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:229:22)
app[web.1]: at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
app[web.1]: at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7) {
app[web.1]: code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
app[web.1]: command: 'CONN'
app[web.1]: }
```

Does anyone face the same issue on paid Heroku dyno? Perhaps, there is any difference in configuration of free dyno vs. hobby dyno in terms of sending requests to the SMTP servers over 25 port?

Comment: Try changing the port alternatively run command `telnet example.com 25` to check if port 25 is blocked or not.

Comment: @LovekeshKumar, I've already checked the mail server's port, it's opened.

Comment: Then it's probably an error with auth. Starting using XOAuth2 and things will work fine according to me. Check this simple article here - https://masashi-k.blogspot.com/2013/06/sending-mail-with-gmail-using-xoauth2.html

Comment: It's not a Gmail SMTP-server (`// no Gmail server`), thus no XOAuth2 issue.

Comment: Which SMTP service you are using?

Comment: From some local provider, kind of «noname», not something famous, you can find in «Top-10 email gateways».